# PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: uuid = uuid[]

Tags: postgresql, kotlin, uuid

I am trying to fetch rows from the table by checking if `uuids` matches any of the values in the array that is passed to the select statement.
The code looks like this:

```
val existingCustomers = fetchRows(
      ctx, generateSQLForTuples(tuples), mapOf("uuids" to customers.map { it["uuid"] as UUID })
  )
```

The `generateSQLForTuples` looks like this:

```
private fun generateSQLForTuples(tuplesList: List<List<String>>):String =
    // language=PostgreSQL
    """
      select id, subcustomer
      from customer
      where uuid in (:uuids)
      union
      select id, subcustomer
      from customer
      where (customer_id, subcustomer) in (${toJdbcTuples(tuplesList)})
    """.trimIndent()
```

But, I get the error:

```
PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: uuid = uuid[]
```

What am I doing wrong here how can I pass an array with UUID values to a select statement?

Comment: It seems you are passing an array, so you need to use `where uuid = any(:uuids)`

Comment: What is `toJdbcTuples`? It looks like you're dealing with a list of lists, not with a list of tuples.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name shouldn't IN do the same job as ANY to compare the value with the values from an array?

Comment: @Leff: not if the parameter is an array `IN` works with a list of values, e.g. `in (1,2,3)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am not sure if I understand the difference between a list and an array here, map function is returning a list with only uuid values, so it should be the same as you mentioned e.g. ```(1, 2, 3)```?

Answer (score 3):

`IN` operator does not work with `ARRAY[]`, it works with a column of rows.

You have two options to solve this problem:

1. Expand an ARRAY using [`unnest()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html)

Eg. `column IN (SELECT unnest((ARRAY[uuid1])::uuid[]))`

2. Use `ANY()` to work with ARRAY

Eg. `WHERE column = ANY((ARRAY[uuid1])::uuid[])`

Answer (score 0):

I tried using IN but it didn't work. I got the error `ERROR: operator does not exist: uuid = uuid[]`.

Instead of using `WHERE SomeColumn IN (@ids)` I've used `WHERE SomeColumn = ANY (@ids)` and it worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

In stead of using the "IN" comparator, you should be using the "=" because if you are using an ARRAY[]